# How to set Content Security Policy (CSP) header for response in Micronaut

Tags: kotlin, micronaut

I want to set these bellow headers value to the HTML response, how should I do that?

```
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'none';
X-Frame-Options: DENY
```

Micronaut version: `3.10.2`